# Null array parameter in query string .net6 swaggerUI

Tags: entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities, swagger-ui, .net-6.0

I am trying to allow support for querying on a date range in my get request. the "after" and "Between" work fine but I'd also like to implement "before". SwaggerUI will not allow me to leave an array value blank for 'Birthday'

**Controller**

```
[HttpGet]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK, Type = typeof(List<Patient>))]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Read([FromQuery] GetPatientsQuery parameters)
    {
        var result = await _mediator.Dispatch(parameters);
        return Ok(result);

    }
```

**Parameter object (Inherited by GetPatientsQuery)**

```
public class GetPatientsParameters
{
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    public DateTime?[]? Birthday { get; set; } //search a range
    public string? Gender { get; set; }
}
```

I thought settings a nullable array of nullables would work here

**Linq To Entity Query**

```
return await _context.Set<Patient>()
                .Where(x => query.FirstName == null || x.FirstName.ToLower().StartsWith(query.FirstName.ToLower()))
                .Where(x => query.LastName == null || x.LastName.ToLower().StartsWith(query.LastName.ToLower()))

                //support searching birthdays in a range
                .Where(x => query.Birthday == null || x.Birthday > (query.Birthday.ElementAtOrDefault(0) ?? DateTime.MinValue))
                .Where(x => query.Birthday == null || x.Birthday < (query.Birthday.ElementAtOrDefault(1) ?? DateTime.MaxValue))

                .Where(x => query.Gender == null || x.Gender.ToLower() == query.Gender.ToLower())

                .ToListAsync();
```

[image: SwaggerUi expects value for nullable date time]

Answer (score 0):

May be a quirk of Swagger UI

calling this endpoint directly yields expected results

```
https://localhost:7283/Patient?Birthday=&Birthday=2022-09-06T21%3A59%3A00.660Z
```

but not this

```
https://localhost:7283/Patient?Birthday=null&Birthday=2022-09-06T21%3A59%3A00.660Z
```